# copy-item powershell issue

Tags: directory-structure, copy-item

This may be a very ridiculous question but when executing the copy-item command, only the main folder is copied MINUS the contents within. for example I have

\server1\parent\child <<---this folder has items nested within but copy-item only moves the folder, not the items within.  I have tried the following 2:

```
copy-item "\\server1\parent\child -destination "\\server2\parent\child

copy-item "\\server1\parent\child\* -destination "\\server2\parent\child
```

but again, the first line only moves the folder and the second lines moves folder and items but items are not moved within the folder.  I was wanting to keep the folder structure the same as from where I am copying it from. I looked at a few places, including here, and I must be missing something.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer right after I posted the question.  I was missing the -recurse option after the \server1\parent\child. The line that now works is

```
copy-item ''\\Server1\parent\child" -recurse -destination "\\Server1\parent\child"
```

Thanks Everyone!